# Split a column using other columns as reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following fields shown below:

```
Tr_Date   Tr_Time  Tr_Data
20130313    43359   41239
20130313    45317   46594
20130313    45920   62223
20130313    51227   51826
20130313    51312   51808
20130313    52131   47516
20130313    52443   61269
20130313    52447   63318
20130313    52453   2709
20130313    52545   61262
20130313    52623   21206
20130313    52655   48123
20130313    53250   29004
20130313    53440   55534
20130313    53503   30380
20130313    53932   46166
20130313    54157   2653
20130313    54325   46262
20130313    54503   2055
20130313    54548   18078
20130313    54557   21660
20130313    54623   54390
20130313    54656   46550
20130313    54700   59238
```

What I need to do is to separate the **Tr_Time** into two columns. The basis will be the **Tr_Date** and the **Tr_Data**. In every **Tr_Date** and **Tr_Data**, There are 2 **Tr_Time** which I have to separate into two different columns. This is actually a database captured from id scanning in timein/out system. However, in and out are saved in one column. I have to do the separation in SQL. In order to manipulate the data for timekeeping in a payroll system.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show example output?

Comment: If the IN and OUT time are saved in one column, then IN is replaced by the OUT time?

Comment: The sample data you've shown isn't very helpful. The 'Tr-Date' values are all the same and I'm not really able to make any sense of the data in the other two columns.
If you understand the data, won't a simple select with a where clause do?

Comment: Which kind of DB is it?

Comment: @trippino It is mentioned in tags.

Comment: @user2560008 if some solution worked please mark it as valid

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the sql-server syntax very well but I think you should use the `GroupBy` function and the `MIN`/`MAX` function (or the `First`, depends on field type), like so:

```
INSERT INTO destTable SELECT 
    Tr_Date, 
    MIN(Tr_Time) as inField, 
    MAX(Tr_Time) as OutField, 
    Tr_Data 
FROM table 
GROUP BY  
    Tr_Date,
    Tr_Data;
```

If fields are not integers you can use something like:

```
INSERT INTO destTable SELECT 
    Tr_Date, 
    FIRST(Tr_Time) as inField, 
    FIRST(Tr_Time) as OutField, 
    Tr_Data 
FROM table 
GROUP BY  
    Tr_Date,
    Tr_Data;
```

And after this you should update your table like so:

```
UPDATE destTable AS a 
    SET OutField = 
       (SELECT Tr_Time 
        FROM table as b 
        WHERE a.Tr_Date = b.Tr_Date 
             AND a.Tr_Data = bg.Tr_Data 
             AND b.Tr_Time <> a.OutField)
```

Maybe you should have the `destTable` table already defined (I don't know), and maybe you should rearrange the query with the right syntax, but I think that the concept can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two rows for each `Tr_Date`, `Tr_Data` combination (IN first, OUT second), your query can look like this:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT 
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tr_Date,Tr_Data ORDER BY Tr_Time) RN
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT
  c_in.Tr_Date
 ,c_in.Tr_Data
 ,c_in.Tr_Time AS Time_In
 ,c_out.Tr_Time AS Time_Out
FROM CTE c_in
LEFT JOIN CTE c_out 
  ON c_in.Tr_Date = c_out.Tr_Date 
  AND c_in.Tr_Data = c_out.Tr_Data
  AND c_in.RN = 1
  AND c_out.RN = 2
WHERE c_in.RN = 1
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45bac/1)**
(Your sample data lacked any out rows, so I've added some extra rows with random numbers)

Comment: why don't simply `SELECT
 Tr_Date, MIN(Tr_Time), MAX(Tr_Time), Tr_Data FROM Table1
 group by Tr_Date, Tr_Data` if he only want to select?

Comment: @trippino Good point, I tend to sometimes overlook the simple solutions :) ... However, if time_out row don't exist yet, I guess NULL should be returned and not same time as time_in

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT  Tr_Date ,
        Tr_Data ,
        MAX(Tr_Time) ,
        MIN(Tr_Time)
FROM    TableName
GROUP BY Tr_Date ,
        Tr_Data
```